# After the installion of django-bootstrap-toolkit, to use the css class in bootstrap, but it didn't work

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

1. I installed the django-bootstrap-toolkit by "sudo pip install django-bootstrap-toolkit".
2. Then I added 'bootstrap_toolkit' to INSTALLED_APPS.
3. After that, I began use it in the template: "Temp.html"

   {% load bootstrap_toolkit %}

   {% csrf_token %}

   ```
   {{ form|as_bootstrap }}

   <div class="form-actions">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   </div>
   ```

But the result is the bootstrap didn't work, the style was the same as didn't use any style. So what's wrong with it. I had followed the steps in https://github.com/tongqi/django-bootstrap-toolkit for serval times.

Comment: Why use a confusing plugin like that and not just use bootstrap's css an js on the client side like any other static files is beyond me

Comment: So you mean I shouldn't use the django-bootstrap-toolkit but use the bootstrap's css and js directly?

Comment: Yes. Bootstrap is a client-side plugin, and techincally, there's no need for a special tool to integrate it with Django which is server-side (and in my experience, it's easier using it directly and I use both together constantly)